# WCF - Net.Tcp in IIS/WAS has stopped working between machines but works locally

Tags: wcf

We have a WCF Service on a remote machine (WIN01S223) that works via the `WsHttpBinding`. An ASP.NET MVC app on machine (WIN01S222) communicates with it over the binding. This is with IIS 7.5 WAS. We implemented another endpoint with `NetTcpBinding`. This was working and now has stopped with the following error.

> Could not connect to net.tcp://win01s223/PortalLoadSimServices10/WorkerService.svc. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:21.0568428. TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.254.47:808.

Note: The system admin says the firewall is not blocking port 808 as this error would seem to indicate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Found it! If this ever happens to you, make sure the netTcp Listner Service hasn't stooped - make sure its started.